# Max - min problem of a quotient of norms

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, normed-spaces

For the $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\-3&-5\end{bmatrix}$

Part 1
Find nonzero vectors  $u$ and $w$ that maximize and minimize respectively the quotient $||Av|| / ||v||$.

Part 2
Among the matrices of rank one, what is the matrix $B$ that is closest to $A$, i.e. such that

max, over all $||v|| = 1$, of

$||A-B||$ is minimal.

I started on part I and applied the matrix $A$ to an arbitrary 2x1 column vector, getting the image $Av$, and took the standard Euclidean norm of this vector.  So it is a function in the two variables $x$ and $y$ - the two components of the arbitrary vector.

I will next take partial derivatives and try to find critical points, max and min.

Am I on the right track or should I go a different route?  This matrix doesn't look special - it's not hermitian, symmetric or anything else that is immediately obvious, so I don't think the Rayleigh quotient or other special theorems apply to this problem, but just wanted to post this anyway, in case you guys have some good tips and suggestions to share (and also for part 2).

Thanks,

Edit:  So I took partial derivatives in the variables x and y, set both equal to zero and obtained two homogeneous equations.  This translates into solving a system of linear equations with two equations and two unknowns - easily done by solving a usual matrix equation.  But I notice that my matrix of coefficients is invertible, so of course row reducing and solving for $x$ and $y$ yielded only the unique solution - the zero vector, (0,0).  But the question asks to find non-zero vectors...

Comment: After asking $59$ questions, you should be using Mathjax to format your questions. It isn't hard. See here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for the tutorial.

Comment: I don't have access to a computer due to the holiday schedule (no access to campus buildings, no internet at home) so I am doing this stuff on my phone - I apologize, @5xum :(

Comment: There is nothing about MathJax that makes it impossible to type on the phone. All you need are dollar signs, backslashes and curly brackets.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks @5xum :).

Comment: Can you write down the equations you got when taking partial derivatives? I assume that's where a mistake occured, but I can only find it if you tell me what you did...

Comment: It was a messy linear system, but I went back to the book, @5xum, and it turns out that there is a corollary to the Rayleigh Quotient - and this corollary is applicable to square matrices that don't have to be self-adjoint.  It states that the max of the above quotient of norms, over all non-zero vectors, is just the square root of the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A^*A$.  My question now is:  since I can compute the max, which always exists and is finite (proved in the book), then what is the minimum of this quotient?  Would it automatically be 1/max?  Thanks...

Comment: @LebronJames Is this needed for optimizing your performance in basketball?  In any event, you might try max/min over the unit circle, and use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: ...my performance has reached a maximum already :(

Comment: hmmm...is your hint regarding part(1) or part(2)?  for part (1), I know now that the norm of a matrix A is just the max (over all nonzero vectors) of ||Ax|| / ||x||, which can be found by computing for the square root of the largest eigenvalue of A*A.  Question is:  once I find this square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^{*}A$, how do I find the vectors u and w that maximize (and minimize) this quotient?  would it be the eigenvector(s) corresponding to the eigenvalue that I took the square root of?